# activating a javascript function from codebehind without clickevent

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function in my aspx page

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openModalpopUp(uri) {
       window.alert(uri);
       $("#popup2").bPopup({ content: 'iframe', contentContainer: '#pContent', loadUrl: uri });
       return false;
}
```

And as part of a linkbutton click in a DataGrid, I want the above openModalpopup to get activated. The code I have in my vb page is

```
   Call GetRevisionPageUrl(imageNbr, ImgRegion, img.Index.IndexType, revision.RevisionSeq, CType(img.NodeId, String))

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "openModalpopUp(" & strRevisionPageUrl & ");", True)
```

When I do a View Source on the page, I see the script with the correct variable passed on to the openModalpopup function. But, the javascript does not seem to get fired. Would appreciate ideas and pointers on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Are you using update panel?

Comment: no. I had the single quote missing. It's firing now.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for pointing it out. what is the best way to avoid it. I do not know the url ahead of time, based on certain actions, i have to pass on the url to the javascipt function. What other ways can I accomplish it?

Comment: @sansid: You need to correctly escape all data before concatenating strings.  Call `Server.JavaScriptStringEncode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing a string it has to be enclosed in apostrophes:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "openModalpopUp('" & strRevisionPageUrl & "');", True)
```

Comment: Probably. If the value is not controlled.

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
"openModalpopUp(" & strRevisionPageUrl & ");"
```

to

```
"openModalpopUp('" & strRevisionPageUrl & "');"
```

You forgot your quotes around your string.